What would be the proper way to connect multiple switches/router to buildings and manage each nodes bandwidth?
We have 3 buildings with a rudimentary network, a main building and 2 others (the main is connected to the other buildings via an outdoor electric junction box).
We're using Starlink at the main building and need to manage the bandwidth and prioritize data used downstream at each of the other buildings Wi-Fi routers.
Here is our current network:

All switches shown are non-managed of various brands, most are 5 port as that is all that's needed at each node.
The goal is to be able to manage the bandwidth to each buildings Wi-Fi router and simplify the network if possible. We also need to use some sort of QoS to prioritize VoIP calls, etc.
What changes to the network or equipment would be needed to do so?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
